# AndroidManifest com multiplas tag <application>

Tags: android, android-manifest

Preciso utilizar as bibliotecas PARSE e VOLLEY em um APP Android, porém, ambas precisam ser declaradas na TAG Application, no `AndroidManifest`, mas observei que pode existir apenas uma TAG Application em um `AndroidManifest`, alguém tem a solução?

Answer (score -1):

Bom, depois de tanto quebrar a cabeça com essa questão que parece simples (e é), resolvi postar a solução para o problema.
Recentemente precisei utilizar as bibliotecas Parse e Volley em uma aplicação que desenvolvi, daí veio o problema, ambas precisam ser declaradas na TAG Aplication do AndroidManifest, na propriedade android:name="pacote.NomeApplication".
Pois bem, o AndroidManifest só aceita uma única TAG Application, mas para contornar essa situação, basta estender (extends) uma classe da outra, exemplo:

arquivo: ParseApplication.java

```
Public class ParseApplication extends Application {
...
}
```

Agora é só estender VolleyApplication de ParseApplication:

arquivo: VolleyApplication.java

```
Public class VolleyApplication extends ParseApplication {
...
}
```

resultado no AndroidManifest:

```
<application
android:name="pacote.VolleyApplication"
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
.
.
.
</activity
</application>
```

É isso, pessoal.

Comment: Fazer uma biblioteca herdar de outra me parece um tanto estranho. Tem certeza que não há outra alternativa?

Comment: Veja [esta resposta no Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491279/androidmanifest-xml-with-multiple-application-tags). Talvez isso ajude.

Comment: Então, por mais que eu tenha pesquisado, essa foi a única solução que encontrei, como sou novato em JAVA, não sei se existe algum tipo de problema com essa prática, mas funcionou que foi uma beleza. Caso eu encontre uma forma mais elegante de contornar essa metodologia, estarei postando outra resposta.

Obrigado pela observação.